# Como pasar substrings en un ArrayList a simples caracteres?

Tags: java, string, poo, substring, concatenación

Estoy desarrolando un programa en el cual se obtienen los substrings de una cadena dada y se orden alfabeticamente. Sin embargo, tambien quiero que al darle un numero este ubique el caracter que esta en la posicion dada por el numero y lo imprima.

Este es mi codigo:

```
package tochararray;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collections;

/**
*
* @author efrias002
*/
 public class ToCharArray {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {



 String s = sub("dbac",6); 

}


private static String sub(String s, int n){

  ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= s.length(); j++) {
            String r = s.substring(i, j);
            lista.add(r);//Se añaden a la lista
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(lista);//Este es el metodo que ordena la lista.

    System.out.println("Las substrings en orden alfabetico:");
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
       System.out.printf(lista.get(i) + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("Los caracteres concatenados:");
    for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){

      System.out.printf(lista.get(i));

    }  

    for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){

    if(n==i){

        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.printf("El caracter en la posicion" + " " +  n + " "  + "es" + " " + lista.get(i));


  }
  }
    return null;
    }



}
```

La cadena es "dbac" y las substrings que da son

```
  a ac b ba bac c d db dba dbac
```

y ya concatenados

```
aacbbabaccddbdbadbac
```

Pero si le digo muestrame el elemento en la posicion 6 me da:

```
  El caracter en la posicion 6 es d
```

Ya que esta tomando las substrings y lo que necesito es que tome caracter por caracter y me diga el caracter en la posicion 6.

Comment: se que es lo que debes hacer, solo necesito saber cual es el caracter esperado en la posición 6

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String sub(String s, int n){

  ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= s.length(); j++) {
            String r = s.substring(i, j);
            lista.add(r);//Se añaden a la lista
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(lista);//Este es el metodo que ordena la lista.

    System.out.println("Las substrings en orden alfabetico:");
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
       System.out.printf(lista.get(i) + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("Los caracteres concatenados:");
    //primero el objeto lista es eso una lista de substring si necesitas
    //el caracter en la pocision n debes guardar el resultado de la 
    //concatenacion en un string al que llame aux
    String aux="";
    for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){

      System.out.printf(lista.get(i));
     //concateno los caracteres 
     aux+=lista.get(i);

    }  
    //el for que habia aqui es innecesario puedes obtener el caracter mediante 
    //el metodocharAt de la clase String y lo obtienes de aux que es la cadena 
    //concatenada
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.printf("El caracter en la posicion" + " " +  n + " "  + "es" + " " + aux.charAt(n));
    return null;
    }
}
```

espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.